# How do I loop a WAV file?

Tags: sounds

For Halloween I've done my front yard up in Pirate style. I have a couple of cannon that I've got the smoke & a red light working at 30 second intervals (too long going to cut it down to 20. My problem is figuring out how to loop a sound file to match the 20 second interval A cannon just looses something in the translation without the BOOM!!! LOL. I have a good single boom WAV track. Now I need to loop it to sync with the smoke & light. If possible on a CD that I can play through some good speakers. MP3 players are only really set up for ear phones & not amplified enough or a big enough (RCA) jack to run through an amp (I have guitar amps I can use though). Any suggestions of a good looping & burning software (free preferably LOL).

Comment: I hate to be the one to break the news, but Hallowe'en was a week ago.  You missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Reaper. It's not free, but the eval version will get you where you need to go.

Lay the cannon sample at the start of the timeline, then create some blank audio to fill in the time up to 20 seconds. Group the two regions into a single region then loop them for as long as you want.

Export the entire timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a program call "Audasity" it's free & an audio track looping program. I have it pretty good at 20 seconds over all (including silence between. But now I'm having trouble burning it to a CD so I can play it next Halloween. But I think it's a glitch in my machine. I've been having some issues. Aint electronics great? LOL

Comment: it's spelled 'Audacity' and the link is https://www.audacityteam.org/. To burn the audio file to CD, you need CD burning software that can create an audio CD.